# Error creating bean with name 'dataTableColumnSpecs' defined in file [tomcat_path\DataTableColumnSpecs.class] javaspring mvc

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, datatable

Hello i want create datatables javaspring mvc

i'm follow this link

http://www.opencodez.com/java/datatable-with-spring-boot.htm

but i have problem 
**Error creating bean with name 'dataTableColumnSpecs' defined in file [tomcat_path\DataTableColumnSpecs.class]**

**Error Log**

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataTableColumnSpecs' defined in file [local_tomcat\hris\WEB-INF\classes\org\hris\datatables\DataTableColumnSpecs.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hris.datatables.DataTableColumnSpecs]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hris.datatables.DataTableColumnSpecs.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5337)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hris.datatables.DataTableColumnSpecs]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hris.datatables.DataTableColumnSpecs.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hris.datatables.DataTableColumnSpecs.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
    ... 30 more

Oct 16, 2017 11:20:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [spring] in web application [] threw load() exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hris.datatables.DataTableColumnSpecs.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5337)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataTableColumnSpecs' defined in file [local_tomcat\hris\WEB-INF\classes\org\hris\datatables\DataTableColumnSpecs.class]: Instantiation of be failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hris.datatables.DataTableColumnSpecs]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hris.datatables.DataTableColumnSpecs.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:828)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hris.datatables.DataTableColumnSpecs]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hris.datatables.DataTableColumnSpecs.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hris.datatables.DataTableColumnSpecs.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
    ... 37 more

Oct 16, 2017 11:21:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet spring
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hris.datatables.DataTableColumnSpecs.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:828)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <!-- context:component-scan base-package="org.bkn.hris.controller" / -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.bkn.hris">
        <context:include-filter type="regex" expression="org.bkn.hris.*"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <beans:bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <beans:property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
        <beans:property name="cookieName" value="myAppLocaleCookie"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="cookieMaxAge" value="3600"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

**DataTableColumnSpecs.java**

```
package org.bkn.hris.datatables;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class DataTableColumnSpecs {

    /** The index. */
    private int index;

    /** The data. */
    private String data;

    /** The name. */
    private String name;

    /** The searchable. */
    private boolean searchable;

    /** The orderable. */
    private boolean orderable;

    /** The search. */
    private String search;

    /** The regex. */
    private boolean regex;

    /** The sort dir. */
    private String sortDir;


    /**
     * Instantiates a new data table column specs.
     *
     * @param request the request
     * @param i the i
     */
    public DataTableColumnSpecs(HttpServletRequest request, int i) {
        this.setIndex(i);
        prepareColumnSpecs(request, i);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the data.
     *
     * @return the data
     */
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the data.
     *
     * @param data the data to set
     */
    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the name.
     *
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the name.
     *
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if is searchable.
     *
     * @return the searchable
     */
    public boolean isSearchable() {
        return searchable;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the searchable.
     *
     * @param searchable the searchable to set
     */
    public void setSearchable(boolean searchable) {
        this.searchable = searchable;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if is orderable.
     *
     * @return the orderable
     */
    public boolean isOrderable() {
        return orderable;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the orderable.
     *
     * @param orderable the orderable to set
     */
    public void setOrderable(boolean orderable) {
        this.orderable = orderable;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the search.
     *
     * @return the search
     */
    public String getSearch() {
        return search;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the search.
     *
     * @param search the search to set
     */
    public void setSearch(String search) {
        this.search = search;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if is regex.
     *
     * @return the regex
     */
    public boolean isRegex() {
        return regex;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the regex.
     *
     * @param regex the regex to set
     */
    public void setRegex(boolean regex) {
        this.regex = regex;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the sort dir.
     *
     * @return the sortDir
     */
    public String getSortDir() {
        return sortDir;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the sort dir.
     *
     * @param sortDir the sortDir to set
     */
    public void setSortDir(String sortDir) {
        this.sortDir = (null != sortDir) ? sortDir.toUpperCase() : sortDir;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the index.
     *
     * @return the index
     */
    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the index.
     *
     * @param index the index to set
     */
    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare column specs.
     *
     * @param request the request
     * @param i the i
     */
    private void prepareColumnSpecs(HttpServletRequest request, int i) {

        this.setData(request.getParameter("columns["+ i +"][data]"));
        this.setName(request.getParameter("columns["+ i +"][name]"));
        this.setOrderable(Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter("columns["+ i +"][orderable]")));
        this.setRegex(Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter("columns["+ i +"][search][regex]")));
        this.setSearch(request.getParameter("columns["+ i +"][search][value]"));
        this.setSearchable(Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter("columns["+ i +"][searchable]")));

        int sortableCol = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("order[0][column]"));
        String sortDir = request.getParameter("order[0][dir]");

        if(i == sortableCol) {
            this.setSortDir(sortDir);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is evident in this stack trace row:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [org.hris.datatables.DataTableColumnSpecs]: 
No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
```

This happens because your `context:component-scan` is scanning your classes and found `DataTableColumnSpecs` that haven't the default constructor, alias constructor with no parameters. Normally you don't need to add explicitly the default constructor unless you specify another constructor with parameters, that is your case.

What you need to do is to add the default constructor to your `DataTableColumnSpecs`, as following:

```
/**
 * Default/empty constructor
 */
public DataTableColumnSpecs() {
    super();
}
```